# Do geometric series or geometric means relate in any way conceptually to geometry?

Tags: terminology

Just like I have always wondered whether there is a conceptual, not just etymological, relationship between the terms "linear algebra" and a "sigma algebra," (there isn't) I would like to know whether geometric series relate in any way to the notion of geometry.

Comment: Yes, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Geometric_construction_of_the_square_root.

Comment: If you know how to represent say,$\sqrt {21}$, geometrically, then it is the same as representing the geometric mean of $3$ and $7$.

Comment: Do a google image search for "geometric mean" and then for "geometric series."